# GCM Push Notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have successfully implemented push notification at my END that is at **Client side**(in My android application).

Server side programming is done in .net.

However, i have followed **each and every step mentioned in the documents** provided by google, "How to implement GCM for push notification".

@**google API Console for developer**, cleanly and successfully able to generate

```
1)Project Id and Sender Id.
2)API auth key.
```

@App, successfully able to generate "**Registration Id**".

**My biggest concern is this,**

When first time i had run my app, and message is pushed from server. My app got notification.

and when i run my app second time, since then i have not received any notification.

Can anyone help regarding this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also facing the same issue which you are facing ie not getting any notification from server site.

If every thing seems to be correct and working fine from your end. Make sure about these few things

```
* Server side did not receive any authentication error message.
  If they do, check and confirm the IP address provided by them is correct and entered
  correctly on Google API console as Credential.

* Each and every app receives unique Registered Id from GCM Server after providing
  relevant and required information to GCM server and that should be stored locally
  in your device.

* Notification alert should be coded so your app can be notified when they receive
  notification.
```

I wish it helps you out somehow.

Comment: Earlier for testing i m using ip address,now i have set to nothing. That is i have not defined any IP address now.... Thanks